# How do I not detect quotation marks when putting html into a string in php?

Tags: php, html, escaping

The title says everything, it detects the quotation marks in the HTML. How do I get it to not do this?

```
$html = fopen($videoname."/video.html", "w") or die("Unable to Play Video");
$txt = "<html><body><video width="1000" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video></body></html>";
fwrite($html, $txt);
fclose($html);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "escape" your quotation marks. Try the following:

```
$txt = "<html><body><video width="1000" controls>
    <source src=\"video.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video></body></html>";
```

Answer (score 2):

as victor says, or:

```
$txt = '<html><body><video width="1000" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video></body></html>';
```

or

```
$txt = <<<EOT
<html><body><video width="1000" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video></body></html>
EOT;
```

Comment: or the third and fourth options you can find here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

This is known as string escaping

```
$html = fopen($videoname."/video.html", "w") or die("Unable to Play Video");
$txt = "<html><body><video width='1000' controls>
    <source src='video.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video></body></html>";
fwrite($html, $txt);
fclose($html);
```

Where you have opened your block with double quotes " " any attributes within must be escaped using single quotes ' ' and vice versa.